# Why does google say that InfraRecorder is a malicious file when downloading from SourceForge?

Tags: burning, dvd-burning, sourceforge

I didn't know which site to put this on.

I was recommended InfraRecorder from many sources for disk burning. However, when downloading from SourceForge, Google says that it is a malicious program. Why?

Comment: Go to Chrome settings and uncheck the box "Enable phishing and malware protection."

Comment: Might be a good time to ensure you don't have any malicious extensions installed.

Comment: Perhaps SourceForge is again bundling crapware to the downloads? It has done so in the past.

Comment: It happens even on by friends comp (it has no extensions).